# Tests of Between-Subjects Effects

Tags: r, spss

I use from code R for table Tests of Between-Subjects Effects calculate in spss but results are diffrent and really I don't  know that why are the reasons? , please help me . thanka alot

```r
fit2222<-manova(cbind(postrunning,postbalance,postbilateral,poststrngth,postupperlimb,postresponse
                  ,postvisumotor,postdexterity)
            ~ group+prerunning+ prebalance+prebilateralcoordination + prestrength + preupperlimbcoordination
              +preresponse+ previsumotor+predexterity  ,data=Data)

summary.aov(fit2222)


input in R
```

[image]

'''
input in spss

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to give a complete answer to this, or at least exactly what you should be doing differently, but it's clear from the output you're showing that you're not comparing the same results in the two packages. Note the numerator degrees of freedom (df) values, which are all 1 in R and 2 in SPSS.